# How to build boost for i386 on 64bit osx?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to get boost 1.53 to link to an app that is compiled for i386. This is on a mac that is 64 bit. It seems that boost is getting built by default as 64 bit so when I try to link to it, I get this error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.dylib,
>   file was built for unsupported file format which is not the
>   architecture being linked (i386)

I tried building boost via this command:

> ./b2 toolset=darwin cxxflags="-arch i386" address-model=32 stage

But it doesn't seem to make a difference. My linker settings are

> -lboost_system -lboost_thread

Do I need to build boost a different way, or link to it differently?

**Edit**

Just figured out that this command seems to build it correctly:

> ./b2 toolset=darwin cxxflags="-arch i386" address-model=32 architecture=x86 stage

and do the same for install

> ./b2 install toolset=darwin cxxflags="-arch i386" address-model=32 architecture=x86 stage

Comment: You are building the app? Or boost?

Comment: @jean, I'm building both.

Comment: If you are building both, then you have two targets. So you need to change the settings on both targets so they match each other. Make sure that `Build Active Architecture only` is set to `No` for both targets.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the architecture i386 in your target configuration:
(`Valid Architectures` in the `Build Setting` of your target)

**However**, if you are building the app, you have two solutions:

- Build the app 32 bits, build a 32 bits version of the library.
- Build the app 64 bits. For that, replace `i386` with `x86_64` and
  change `Architectures` as well as `Valid Architectures`.

[image]

Comment: This is actually already set to 32-bit Intel for my target.

Comment: There are three things to check: `Architectures` to `32-bits intel`, `Build Active Architecture only` to `No` and `Valid Architectures` to i386.

Comment: **Something is unclear**. You are trying to link your app to `libboost_system.dylib`, right? If yes, you actually need to change all settings for 64 bits

Comment: I'd like to keep my app setting to be 32 bit and link to 32 bit boost. The problem is that boost is currently compiling as 64 bit and I'm not sure how to compile it as 32 bit.

Comment: If you are building both, then you have two targets. So you need to change the settings on both targets so they match each other. Make sure that `Build Active Architecture only` is set to `No` for both targets. Just like in the picture.

Comment: @NotDan You have build settings in three places: On your two targets and in your project configuration.